# Or , In result empty when Where have empty array

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I have this code :

```
Films.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Genres,
    attributes: ['slug'],
    where: {
      [Op.or]: req.body.genres
    },
    through: {
      attributes: []
    }
  }, ],
  raw: false
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res.length)
  resp.send(res)
})
```

I really want it to still print all the result even if the array is empty.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? What is your input and what do yo want as an output? Why do you want to print all the results even the array is empty, since it is a filter and this is how it works, by filtering data?

Comment: Why i use [Op.and] . it can still print out the results even if the array is empty ?

Comment: Is `req.body.genres` an array?

Comment: Your use of `through` is also incorrect - can you include your model definitions?

Comment: doublesharp : yes req.body.genres is array , and i think my through nothing related to this